# google sheet has background colour and border on one cell, that I can not remove

Tags: google-sheets

I have one cell with a green background, and a border. I have tried to remove formatting. I have checked that there are no conditional formatting. I even checked filters (that was the cause last time something strange happened).

How can I remove this formatting?
What are the different ways to cause formatting?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the search/find feature. For some reason a search had been done earlier (much earlier). The found cells were highlighted with a green background and a black border.

Screenshot:
[image]